# module has no attribute

Tags: python

I have a directory with a number of `.py` files in it. each file defines some  classes. I also have an empty `__init__.py` in the directory.

For example:

```
myproject
    __init__.py
    mymodule
        __init__.py
        api.py
        models.py
        views.py
```

I am trying to import `mymodule` and access the classes defined in all these files:

```
from myproject import mymodule

print mymodule.api.MyClass
```

It gives me an error saying that `mymodule` has no attribute `api`. Why?  And why I can access just one of the files (`models.py`) and not the others?

```
In [2]: dir(banners)
Out[2]:
['__builtins__',
 '__doc__',
 '__file__',
 '__name__',
 '__package__',
 '__path__',
 'models']
```

Answer (score 117, accepted):

The problem is submodules are not automatically imported. You have to explicitly import the `api` module:

```
import myproject.mymodule.api
print myproject.mymodule.api.MyClass
```

If you really insist on `api` being available when importing `myproject.mymodule` you can put this in `myproject/mymodule/__init__.py`:

```
import myproject.mymodule.api
```

Then this will work as expected:

```
from myproject import mymodule

print mymodule.api.MyClass
```

Comment: Isn't this a bit cumbersome? Is there a way to switch on importing of sub-modules (with the full qualifying names, e.g foo.bar.baz) by default?

Comment: I'm fine doing the full import, but in the rest of the code I'd like to drop `myproject` and refer to `mymodule.api` which does not seem to be possible?

Comment: @AmirRosenfeld No, there is no such way, and there **cannot possibly** be such a way, because *the file system does not actually dictate* where the sub-modules are or what all their names are. Python allows for huge amounts of customization of the import system. Aside from that, it would be a terrible default behaviour, because in most cases it would slow down all the top-level imports in order to import huge amounts of code that isn't actually used later.

Comment: @Alper Using relative imports within the package will save you a lot of typing. More complex renamings are possible, but they require a proper understanding of the import system which is probably beyond the scope of even a separate Stack Overflow Q&A, let alone the comments section.

Answer (score 43):

Also check whether you didn't name your python file the same as the module you are trying to import.

Comment: Yes, this is a strange piece of Python rubric, that the filename must be different from the module name. Be warned!

Comment: Oh wow, that's a difficult one to google!

Comment: The file name **does not** need to differ from the module name. In fact, the file name **for the module that you are implementing**, by definition, dictates the module name. This is a **completely unrelated** problem that comes up when you want to import a **different module** from the current file, but the current file has the same name as the other module you want to import. The problem is that **every Python source code file defines a module**, whether or not you intend for it to be `import`ed. The modules defined by source code files can, therefore, attempt to import themselves.

Comment: The canonical for this problem is [Importing a library from (or near) a script with the same name raises "AttributeError: module has no attribute" or an ImportError or NameError](/q/36250353).

Answer (score 2):

Modules don't work like that.

```
from myproject.mymodule import api
print api.MyClass
```

Comment: I know I can do that. Is it possible to do using the dotted names?

Comment: @akonsu, simply do `import myproject.mymodule.api` then and access it through `myproject.mymodule.api.MyClass`.

Comment: well, i think this is a question about the language in general, not about how I can get my code to work. I am curious as to whether this can be achieved. can I make it access my classes through 'mymodule.api...' without the leading 'myproject'?

Comment: you could do `import myproject.mymodule as mymodule` but it seems confusing to me

Answer (score -5):

You need an `__init__.py` in the myproject directory too. So your module structure should be:

```
myproject
    __init__.py
    mymodule
        __init__.py
        api.py
        models.py
        views.py
```

Comment: That's exactly the module structure in the question...

Comment: Aside from that, since Python 3.3 empty `__init__.py` files **are not required** to set up directories as packages (although they do influence the lookup order for absolute imports). A missing `__init__.py` **is not** the reason for a relative import failing in modern Python.