# Import Confusion with Packages

Tags: python, import, scikit-learn

I'm about to mess around with Adaboost in `sklearn`, but I just wanted to clarify a small difference that I'm having conceptually.

I've read through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7948494/whats-the-difference-between-a-python-module-and-a-python-package) stack overflow article. I've also breezed through some other stack articles with weird import errors. However, I'm still a little confused on why one of these snippets of code works, while the other breaks.

Basically, I'm just messing around with different ways to import sklearn.ensemble. I figured because sklearn is a package, we could do this:

```
import sklearn
clf = sklearn.ensemble.AdaBoostClassifier
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'ensemble'
```

The error tells me that ensemble is not an attribute. I guess this makes sense, because ensemble is itself a package.

This snipped of code works though:

```
import sklearn.ensemble
clf = sklearn.ensemble.AdaBoostClassifier
```

My question is, what is the distinction? If we import a package, shouldn't it be fine to reference packages within that super-package? Why would this not be allowed? Feel free to just link me documentation, but I wasn't sure about the best place to look.

Thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8899198/module-has-no-attribute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When used by itself, the `import` keyword is always followed by a module, not a package:

```
import my_module
```

If the module that you want to import lives within a package, you can use the dot notation to import that module:

```
import my_package.my_module
```

The confusion arises because the name of a package can also be used as the name for the `__init__.py` module within that package.
When you `import sklearn`, you are not `import`ing all the package contents, but only the module `sklearn.__init__.py`.

Therefore:

```
import sklearn #imports the contents of sklearn.__init__.py
import sklearn.ensemble # imports the contents of sklearn.ensemble.py
```

Another way to import things is the construct

```
from <module> import <attributes>
```

In this case, similar rules apply: the `from` keyboard is followed by a module, not a package. So, if

```
from sklearn import an_awesome_function
```

then you are importing `an_awesome_function` defined in the module `sklearn.__init__.py`, which is part of the package `sklearn`.