# Opencv python cv2 code ,"cv2 has no attribute .__version__" error

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, python

I can successfully get the cv2 version from command line:

```
>>> import cv2
>>> cv2.__version__
'3.4.4'
```

But not when I run a script with that code in the Python 3.7.1 Shell (see image [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/605Ki.png))

```
import cv2
print (cv2.__version__)
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "B:\Users\Ravi\Desktop\Opencv2\cv2.py", line 1, in <module>
    import cv2
  File "B:\Users\Ravi\Desktop\Opencv2\cv2.py", line 2, in <module>
    print (cv2.__version__)
AttributeError: module 'cv2' has no attribute '__version__'
```

How can I solve this problem? Not only the version but none of cv2 code works.

Comment: How did you install openCV?

Comment: using pip install opencv-python command

Comment: Seems to be working fine for me. Can you check that whether the same python is executing the file and the console

Comment: Is it possible that you have a file named `cv2.py`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [module has no attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8899198/module-has-no-attribute)