# Python module has no attribute import error

Tags: python, function, import, python-import, pythonpath

I'm getting `module has no attribute import error`. I've done a bit of research and followed the answer in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8899198/module-has-no-attribute), but still doing something wrong.

I have the following project structure:

```
projectFolder
     __init__.py
     main.py
     subfolder
        __init__.py
        api.py
        models.py
        views.py
```

I would like to run a function contained in `subfolder/api.py` from `main.py`.

I've imported the file in `subfolder/__init__.py` as follows:

```
import projectFolder.subfolder.api
```

In `main.py` I've included this code:

```
from projectFolder import api

def function():
    get_api_function()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this import:

```
from subfolder.api import get_api_function
```

If the `subfolder` is on the python path it should work