# module 'basic_dataset' has no attribute 'getRowData'

Tags: python

i have a `basic_dataset.py` which contains the below function.

```
def getRowData():
    rowDt = np.full((80,20), -1)
    rowDt[:,0] =  np.random.choice([0,1,2],80) # Set the first column
    return  rowDt
```

Then i made another file called `main.ipynb`, **in the same directory**, and tried to access `getRowData()` function using the below code:

```
import basic_dataset

basic_dataset.getRowData()
```

But, it complains with:

```
AttributeError: module 'basic_dataset' has no attribute 'getRowData'
```

I have seen [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8899198/module-has-no-attribute), but i do not think, i can use it.

Comment: Why are you calling getMainDataSet() if you want getRowData()?

Comment: Does it help to restart the Python interpreter?

Comment: @mkrieger1 how may i do it?

Comment: How are you running this code? If you close that problem completely and then try to run it again, does the problem still exist?

Comment: i am running it on `jupyter notbook` on `chrome`

Comment: You can try restarting your `main.ipynb` in jupyter notebook by clicking on the fast forward button (⏩) on the menu bar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After fixing your code, You can restart your main.ipynb in jupyter notebook by clicking on the fast forward button (⏩) on the menu bar.