# module 'sample_project' has no attribute 'data'

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, python-import, python-3.8

I thought I understand python import system, but it looks like I was wrong.
For some reason, I cannot use modules from my package unless I explicitly import them in the `__init__.py` or in the script code. This is not what the [documentation](https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/packaging-projects/) says and I have other projects (e.g., [this one](https://github.com/googleinterns/new-semantic-parsing)) that don't have this kind of issue.

To illustrate it, I created a super simple example. A project with a following structure:

```
sample_project
├── sample_project
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── data.py
└── setup.py
```

`setup.py` looks like this

```py
import setuptools

setuptools.setup(name='sample_project', packages=setuptools.find_packages())
```

and `data.py` like this

```py
class Data:
    pass
```

`__init__.py` is empty.

After `pip install -e .` I can `import sample_project`, but `sample_project.data` throws

```py
AttributeError: module 'sample_project' has no attribute 'data'
```

Note that `data.py` is not inside the submodule, so the issue is different from [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8899198/module-has-no-attribute).
This happens either if I am in the project directory or outside it.

I can fix it via `import sample_project.data` either in my script or in the `__init__.py`, but I don't understand why it does not work. It feels like the default `__all__` does not work for some reason.

In the [project](https://github.com/googleinterns/new-semantic-parsing) I mentioned above I have multiple python files inside `new_semantic_parsing` directory. Some of them are imported in the `__init__.py`, some are not, but I don't have this problem with either of them.

E.g.

```py
import new_semantic_parsing
new_semantic_parsing.utils
```

works fine even though `utils` is not explicitly imported in the `__init__.py`.

Clearly, there is an issue somewhere, but I can't see it.

Comment: It looks like the module is not getting imported if it is not imported somewhere in the source code (some other module).