# Why can't Main Module see sub-module inside it?

Tags: python, import, importerror, nameerror

I am editing to minimize to a reproducible example:

Contents of cal.py

```
import M1

M1.SM1.nice_hello.hello()
```

Directory structure:

```
M1/
├── __init__.py
└── SM1
    ├── __init__.py
    └── nice_hello.py
```

Contents of SM1/nice_hello.py:

```
def hello():
    print(f'Hello my friend!!!')
```

All other files (**init**.py files) are empty.

To run cal.py:

```
export PYTHONPATH=/PATH/TO/M1 ; python cal.py
```

But that gives me following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "cal.py", line 3, in <module>
    M1.SM1.nice_hello.hello()
AttributeError: module 'M1' has no attribute 'SM1'
```

Comment: Is cal.py at the same level as M1?

Comment: How exactly do you run `cal.py`? From the command line? From what directory?

Comment: I do `export PYTHONPATH=/PATH/TO/M1` ; the I run using `python cal.py`

Comment: And where is cal.py in your directory structure?

Comment: cal.py can be anywhere, so long as PYTHONPATH is set, it should not matter.

Comment: May be so, but this is not mentioned in your question, and without that information, it is not reproducible.

Comment: updated and added.

Comment: I believe https://stackoverflow.com/a/8899345 answers your question, together with [section 6.4 from the Python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#packages). It also helps to check `sys.modules` to find out which modules have been loaded, and use [`dir()`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#packages) to see which names they define.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should work if you import the whole module name, i.e. in the file `cal.py`

```
import M1.SM1.nice_hello

M1.SM1.nice_hello.hello()
```

Comment: But why is M1 not able to use SM1, when it is inside it?

Comment: Submodules are not imported automatically, but you could generate this behaviour by doing a chain of imports in the respective ```__init__.py```-files.

Comment: Is there any way to import Submodules when I import the MainModule.

Comment: In this example, when you include the line ```import M1.SM1.nice_hello``` in ```M1.__init__.py```, you can just import M1 in the main module and then call ```M1.SM1.nice_hello.hello()```. Alternatively, you can add ```import M1.SM1``` in ```M1/__init__.py``` and ```import M1.SM1.nice_hello```  in ```SM1.__init__.py```.

Answer (score 1):

Submodules are not imported recursively, if you want that to happen you can do the below: -

A) Create **init**.py file inside M1 module ( I think you already have that )

B) Have the below code in your **init**.py file : -

```
import importlib
import pkgutil

def import_submodules(package, recursive=True):
""" Import all submodules of a module, recursively, including subpackages

:param package: package (name or actual module)
:type package: str | module
:rtype: dict[str, types.ModuleType]
"""
if isinstance(package, str):
    package = importlib.import_module(package)
results = {}
for loader, name, is_pkg in pkgutil.walk_packages(package.__path__):
    full_name = package.__name__ + '.' + name
    results[full_name] = importlib.import_module(full_name)
    if recursive and is_pkg:
        results.update(import_submodules(full_name))
return results
```

This will help you import all the submodules inside that package ( M1)

Now in your cal.py do below: -

```
import M1
M1.import_submodules(M1)
def hello():
    print(f'Hello my friend!!!')
```

Hopefully this will resolve your issue and might guide you on how to import modules recursively in python

Reference :- [How to import all submodules?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3365740/how-to-import-all-submodules)

Please reach out in comments if any further clarification is required. Will be happy to help