# An error occurred: module 'openai' has no attribute 'ChatCompletion'

Tags: python, openai-api, gpt-4

I'm trying to build a discord bot that uses the GPT-4 API to function as a chatbot on discord. I have the most recent version of the OpenAI library but when I run my code it tells me "An error occurred: module 'openai' has no attribute 'ChatCompletion'"

I tried uninstalling and reinstalling the OpenAI library, I tried using the completions endpoint and got the error "This is a chat model and not supported in the v1/completions endpoint. Did you mean to use v1/chat/completions?"

This is the snippet of code thats giving me issues:

```
async def get_gpt_response(prompt, history):
    history_strings = [f"{message['role']}: {message['content']}" for message in history] # update history format
    chat_prompt = '\n'.join(history_strings + [f"user: {prompt}"])
    
    completions = openai.ChatCompletion.create(
        engine=config["model"],
        prompt=chat_prompt,
        max_tokens=config["max_tokens"],
        n=1,
        temperature=config["temperature"],
    )
    return completions.choices[0].text.strip().split('assistant:', 1)[-1].strip()
```

Comment: Yes in the code snippet I provided you can see it is using the ChatCompletions endpoint rather than the Completions endpoint

Comment: First of all, did you get access to the GPT-4 API? Second of all, your code looks like you want to use the GPT-3 API. Which OpenAI model do you want to use? This question needs more focus.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [module has no attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8899198/module-has-no-attribute)

Comment: openai has changed the API, at least that's was the problem for me
https://github.com/openai/openai-python

Answer (score 10):

Make sure you don’t have a file called “openai.py”

Comment: Such a simple and yet natural mistake :D

Answer (score 3):

I experienced exactly the same error, even after just installation the OpenAi library.  I ran the script below:

pip install --upgrade openai

Which gave me that latest version with ChatCompletion as a method.

Comment: This was the case for me, had to upgrade using: `pip install -U openai`. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Yes i have the file nameed openai.py after changes the name it runs

Comment: I think the answer to remove the file (i.e. by renaming it) already exists [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76084452/4883195), no need to repeat it

Answer (score 2):

So I also faced the same issue and this is because of the *latest version of the `openai` library is not on your system* , could be because when you install from `requirements.txt` or maybe something else but here's how I solved it :

You have to just uninstall the current `openai` library, and install the latest `openai` library version.

```
pip uninstall openai

pip install openai
```

Answer (score 2):

https://pypi.org/project/openai/

like this:

```py
from openai import OpenAI

client = OpenAI(
    # defaults to os.environ.get("OPENAI_API_KEY")
    api_key="My API Key",
)

chat_completion = client.chat.completions.create(
    messages=[
        {
            "role": "user",
            "content": "Say this is a test",
        }
    ],
    model="gpt-3.5-turbo",
)
```

Answer (score 2):

Still I got the error after running upgrade command .The current version of open ai NOV 2023 is 1.1.1  ,I fixed it by specifying  version of 0.28.0 or 0.28.1.

Answer (score 2):

I think in latest verison of OpenAI chat completions is not available. May be some other method is there. If you want your code to work as it, then simply uninstall current OpenAI and install older version by following command. It worked for me.

```py
pip uninstall openai
pip install -Iv  openai==0.27.8
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have the latest OpenAI library. I have the same issue and resolved it by upgrade openai 26.5 to 27.2 version.

Answer (score 0):

The end-point strictly depends on the engine used for completion.
So which engine did you used? I can't try GPT4 cause it's not already open to everyone but i suppose API are similar to GPT3.5
For example if you use

```
openai.Completion.create
```

you have to use a text-completion engine like *text-davinci-003*

If you use

```
openai.ChatCompletion.create
```

you have to use a chat engine like *gpt-3.5-turbo*

here a little snippet of code where `self.COMPLETIONS_MODEL = "gpt-3.5-turbo"`

```
  COMPLETIONS_API_PARAMS = {
      # We use temperature of 0.0 because it gives the most predictable, factual answer.
      "temperature": 0.0,
      "max_tokens": 256,
      "model": self.COMPLETIONS_MODEL,
  }    
  prompt = self.construct_prompt(
      query,
      document_embeddings,
      df
  )
  
  messages = [
      {"role":"system","content":"Rispondi a domande sull'utilizzo del servizio WebAPI di Passepartout"},
      {"role":"user","content":prompt}
    ]
  response = openai.ChatCompletion.create(
              messages=messages,
              **COMPLETIONS_API_PARAMS
          )
```

Answer (score 0):

Be sure your python version is 3.8 or 3.9. I used 3.6 and had the same issue, it was not until I upgraded that it worked correctly

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34524252)

Answer (score 0):

pip install --upgrade openai --user

This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

pip install --upgrade httpcore

This worked for me

Comment: do you know why?

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same issue as you and resolved it in the following way:

Firstly, I uninstalled the packages:

```
pip uninstall langchain langchain-openai langchain-community langchain_experimental
```

Then, I installed:

```
pip install langchain langchain_openai
```

Now, my versions are as follows:
langchain: 0.1.12
langchain-openai: 0.0.8
Please note the difference between ”langchain-openai“ and ”langchain_openai“.